# How to CHANGE or DELETE Name of the User on Debian 10 (IN DESKTOP)

Tags: interface, debian, settings, desktop

Sorry for this simple question, but I didn't find this information.

I want to know, how I can **change name or delete name of the user**, in easy way, on **Debian 10** in **DESKTOP UI interface** not *via terminal*.

In windows, for example, I can write users and immediately will have menu from where I'll be able to Create, Delete or Modify users.

That you very much in advance for the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a GNOME package [`gnome-system-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/gnome-system-tools):

> The GNOME System Tools are a fully integrated set of tools aimed to make easy the job that means the computer administration on an UNIX or Linux system. They're thought to help from the new Linux or UNIX user to the system administrators.
>
> Its main advantages are:
>
> - An user-friendly interface to carry out the main administration tasks.
> - The use of a common user interface in every system.
> - A common structure that makes easy the development of new system tools.
>
> Nowadays there are tools for managing:
>
> - Users and groups
> - Date and time
> - Network options
> - Services
> - Shares (NFS and Samba)

You can install with `synaptic` or via command line per

```
sudo apt install gnome-system-tools
```

The application to change users and groups is `users-admin` (if invoked from a terminal) and availabe in the menu `Settings` -> `Users and Groups` (or similar if you're not running Xfce).

I'm running Xfce and not the GNOME desktop environment and some icons appear to be missing on some buttons, but that's not really an issue since all buttons have a text.

I couldn't find an option to change the user id of an user, but you can change the user name (full name), account type (Administrator or Desktop user), password, home directory and user privileges, add/delete users, disable accounts, manage groups etc. pp.